# Cool way to reset the browser action badge?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have an extension that implements a browser action.
Of course, the browser action is allways visible, but it has a special significance in certain urls.  So, I use filtered events to listen to those urls and set the proper badge

```
chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(
    function(tab){
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
            text:'bdge',
            tabId: tab
        });
    },
    {'url':[{hostSuffix: 'somedomain.com', pathPrefix: 'somePath/'}]}
);
```

Is there some "elegant" way to reset the badge when the user navigates out from that page, without listening every single tab navigation?
Should I execute a content script to hang on some exiting event and send a message?

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that a good solution would be to use [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated).

In your background page, you would have something like that:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    // using a regex or however else you want to test the URL
    if (/somedomain\.com\/somePath\//.test(changeInfo.url)) {
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
            text: 'bdge',
            tabId: tabId
        });
    } else {
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
            text: '',
            tabId: tabId
        });
    }
});
```

I know you wrote "without listening every single tab navigation" but I'm not sure why you want to avoid this.

Comment: A good reason to "avoid listening to every single tab navigation" is because it makes [event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html) more effective. If an event is triggered the whole time, there's almost no point in using an event page over a [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html).

Comment: Rob is right, that's the spirit.  But I think Boucher's answer is a way of telling there is no such way :)  I'm considering executing a content script with window.unbeforeunload=function(){chrome.runtime.sendMessage('unloading')};

Answer (score 3):

This is what documentation doesn't tell you: Chrome actually resets badge automatically when user navigates away.

When you set a browser action's badge only to a specific tab, like

```
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
  text: 'ABCD', // My badge's text should be only 4 characters long
  tabId: 1234  // Any tab, ussually a var here, not a constant
});
```

Chrome shows the badge on the browser action button only when that tab is the active tab in the window.  Its text resets to '' when the user navigates away in that tab.  No need for special action to reset it.

Comment: I'm trying to do this as well, however it doesn't seem to be working. I must be missing something, but Google's docs don't explain how to fully use the TabId parameter.